# Tracking when variables get updated

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, variables, variable-watchers

I have a problem with `org-mode`'s agenda view. While I've set `org-agenda-files` to `'("~/org/")` invariably when I finally spin up <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-agenda` I find that `org-agenda-files` just points to one org-file. Obviously something is deciding just to include the last org-file I viewed but I'm having trouble working out what. Is there any way to trap when this variable is changed and display or log some sort of backtrace?

Comment: From the `org-agenda-files` docstring, "If an entry is a directory, all files in that directory that are matched by `org-agenda-file-regexp` will be part of the file list." By default, that regexp matches all files with `.org` extension in that directory. Can you tell how you have your .org files organized? Do they belong in the `~/org/` folder directly? Or are they in sub-directories under that?

Comment: ageneda -> agenda

Comment: @kaushalmodi: yeah, my ~/org/ is full of org files each with a bunch of TODOs in them (I have one per "topic" with an index.org).

Comment: What version of `org` are you using?  Also could you do the following to test:  Run `emacs -q` then in scratch point to your installation of Org `(add-to-list 'load-path "path/to/org")` if from ELPA or Git, if using built-in you can disregard.  Then in scratch `(require 'org)` `(setq org-agenda-files "~/org/")` `(org-agenda nil "t")`.  See if your TODOs all show up.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin: Latest org for the org ELPA archive (current 8.2.7c on this box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this situation, I find that the best way to figure out what's going
on into is to visit my `~/.emacs.d/` and run `rgrep`.

### Searching your configs

The following snippet, taken from here, makes sure that `rgrep`
doesn't go into the `elpa/` subdir (since you're sure to find dozens
of useless hits in there).

```
(eval-after-load 'grep
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories "auto")
     (add-to-list 'grep-find-ignored-directories "elpa")))
```

Then I just run

```
M-x rgrep RET org-agenda-files RET *.el RET ~/.emacs.d/
```

which will find any reference to `org-agenda-files` in my
configuration. If it's a problem with my configs, this will find it.

### Searching Elsewhere

If the above doesn't find anything, it means there's an Elpa package
causing trouble. So I do

```
M-x rgrep RET org-agenda-files RET *.el RET ~/.emacs.d/elpa/
```

This will usually yield **a lot** of results, but there are ways to go
through them quickly. For instance, it's very unlikely that org-mode
itself is causing this problem. So it's safe to ignore all hits that
come from inside org-modes installation directory.

Comment: Sadly the only place I find it referenced (apart from my config set-up) is in the ELPA version of org. Hence wondering if there was a better way to trap when org updated it.

Comment: Mystery solved! In the end I found the offending line in ~/.emacs.d/my-custom.el which is what _custom-file_ points at. As this is loaded at the end of my init.el it was over-writing what my-org.el had set up. Also as my elisp files are in a sub-dir why I didn't find it earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Another option you have is to track the value of this variable throughout the execution of `org-agenda`, that *has* to tell you where the problem is.

1. Evaluate the following code:

   ```
   (global-set-key [f1] (lambda () (interactive) (message "%s" org-agenda-files)))
   ```
2. Visit the function with `M-x find-function RET org-agenda`.
3. Edebug it with `C-u C-M-x`.
4. Call the function, `M-x org-agenda`.
5. Gradually step through it by pressing `n`, and monitor the value of the variable by hitting `F1`.

At some point inside the `org-agenda` function, you'll hit `F1` and the value of `org-agenda-files` will have changed. That will tell you where to look.

Comment: You could also redefine the function with a bunch of messages, if you don't want to Edebug.

Answer (score 3):

Since 26.1, you can use [`add-variable-watcher`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Watching-Variables.html) to track the variable where and how be changed.

```
 Function: add-variable-watcher symbol watch-function
```

Because the `watch-function` will be called with 4 arguments: `symbol`, `newval`, `operation`, and `where`, you can simply add a watcher in your `init.el`, for example,

```
(add-variable-watcher 'tab-width (lambda (&rest x) (message "Oops! tab-width changed: %S" x)))
```

which gives you some messages like

```
Oops! tab-width changed: (tab-width 2 set #<buffer xxx.el>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you ever using <kbd>C-c [</kbd> (`org-agenda-file-to-front`) or <kbd>C-c ]</kbd> (`org-remove-file`) while in an `org` file?

These overwrite the current `org-agenda-files` with a hardcoded list of files that will no longer use your defined `~/org/` as a source.

Also if you are setting it to `~/org/` please ensure that the agenda files you want are in that folder with `.org` for the extension.  Otherwise they will not be detected.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you don't expect the list of agenda files to change very frequently, it's better to add that list of files to something like `~/org/agenda.files` and set `org-agenda-files` to `~/org/agenda.files`.

Comment: Not consciously. Indeed they are not mapped to useful keys for me.